# Beginner need help w/ html: list and image not showing up

Tags: html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Rooms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1> Welcome</h1>
        <p>Enjoy your stay</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

.nav li{
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    }

.jumbotron{
    background-image:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NPN-yWZyRIM/T4jMz_3o0SI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LGEgW7642Rs/s1600/Greenlake_Room-Greenlake-01-1061468546-O.jpg');
    height:300px;
    }
```

My ul and background image do not show up when i run the code. Please help, im a beginner.

disregard:..........................................................................................................................

Answer (score 3):

You Missed a quotes in this line

```
background-image:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NPN-yWZyRIM/T4jMz_3o0SI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LGEgW7642Rs/s1600/Greenlake_Room-Greenlake-01-1061468546-O.jpg');
```

To be corrected as

```
background-image:url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NPN-yWZyRIM/T4jMz_3o0SI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LGEgW7642Rs/s1600/Greenlake_Room-Greenlake-01-1061468546-O.jpg');
```

Comment: thanks! what about the ul please and for some reason the image still does not show up

Answer (score 0):

You  miss single quotes at the beggining of the image url

Try this

```
background-image:url('http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-NPN-yWZyRIM/T4jMz_3o0SI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LGEgW7642Rs/s1600/Greenlake_Room-Greenlake-01-1061468546-O.jpg');
```